# Regular tournaments

Tags: graph-theory

Let $T=(V,E)$ be a tournament. We call it *regular* if all vertices have the same out-degree. It is not hard to see that there are no regular tournaments on an even number of points.

Let $n>0$ be an integer. If $T_1, T_2$ are regular tournaments on $2n+1$ vertices, do we always have $T_1\cong T_2$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Start with a $K_9$ and compose a tournament of directed cycles built by chords of same "length" in the 9-gon. So there are three $C_9$ and one $3C_3$ involved. Now if you reverse the orientation of just one $C_3$, the resulting tournament should be non isomorphic.

Comment: Where you have written "one $3C_3$', did you mean "three $C_3$"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes if you want. I looked at it as a 2-factor. :-)

Answer (score 8):

For $n=1$ you have the rock-paper-scissors tournament, and for $n=2$ it's the rock-paper-scissor-lizard-Spock tournament :). Already for $n=3$ there are three nonisomorphic tournaments which satisfy your regularity condition. You can see them here ["Rock-Paper-Scissors Meets Borromean Rings"](http://www.math.grin.edu/~chamberl/papers/rps.pdf), by Marc Chamberland and Eugene A. Herman. You can find the first few numbers of such tournaments in [OEIS A096368](https://oeis.org/A096368).

Answer (score 4):

For questions like this you should head for OEIS: http://oeis.org/A096368 .

Also, the asymptotic number of regular tournaments grows much faster than $n!$, so the number of isomorphism types must also grow fast. [Combinatorica, 10 (1990) 367-377](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/rt.pdf) .

Answer (score 2):

The picture in this tweet gives you the minimal counterexample which is $n=3$.
https://twitter.com/Jun_Gitef17/status/456056921405935617
The pairs that come in the diagonals of the hexagon are directed so that everyone has $d_{\mathrm{in}}=d_{\mathrm{out}}$.

For each pairs, a "paper can cover rock"-style explanation is provided in Japanese, but since it's out of topic, I'll leave it to your imagination.

Comment: To be more precise, this directed graph is not isomorphic to the "trivial construction", where you line up $n=7$ vertices in an $n$-gon shape, and then have directed edges connecting vertices that are distance $1,2,\ldots,(n-1)/2$ apart always in the (say) clock-wise direction.